# Very slow SQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm having some major issues with an SQL statement, the following statement causes so much stress to the MySQL engine it pretty much hangs:

```
select c.title, c.initial, c.surname, c.labelno, c.email, br1.bookingdate
from explorer.booking_record br1
inner join explorer.client c
on c.labelno = br1.labelno
and email not like ''
where br1.bookingdate >= '2009-01-01'
and br1.bookingdate < '2009-01-31'
and c.labelno Not In (Select labelno from explorer.booking_record br2 where br2.labelno = br1.labelno and br2.bookingdate >= '2010-01-01' and br2.bookingdate < '2010-01-31')
```

I've tried a few variations on the same, without the joins and two sub-statements, adding 'order by' as advised by the documentation. There aren't actually that many records in the database, booking_record has ~500,000 records and client has ~450,000. If I let the query run it's usually got about 20 results after 70-80 seconds, but this causes the service to go into a loop-like state.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Daniel.

Comment: Have you defined indexes on labelno & bookingdate ( or a complex one on both ) ?

Comment: I don't actually have any control over the database itself, so I couldnt tell you - I'll have a look into it as indexes appears to be a common topic here

Comment: Ok I've had a look and labelno is an index in client, but the index in booking_record is on bookingref (not actually used in this query)

Comment: Well, then you could try adding one on bookingdate. I should make a big difference.

Comment: I'll have to see, unfortunately it's a load of data pulled from a flat file unix system - the data is pulled every night and batch dumped into this mysql database so we can access it. If I add a key it may mess up the job.

Comment: Yep, it'll most probably slow down the job. Still, you really need the index if you have so many records, otherwise I think it'll always go for a full table scan which is pretty time expensive. A complex index on labelno & bookingdate  would probably do the job, though depending on what other queries you're using it may be better to use 2 indexes.

Comment: Can I ask why you have "and email not like ''" as part of the join and not as part of the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the following columns are indexed:

```
explorer.booking_record.labelno
explorer.booking_record.bookingdate
explorer.booking_record.labelno
explorer.client.labelno
explorer.client.email
```

Now try the following query:

```
select c.title, c.initial, c.surname, c.labelno, c.email, br1.bookingdate
from explorer.booking_record br1
left outer join explorer.booking_record br2 on br2.labelno = br1.labelno
    and br2.bookingdate >= '2010-01-01' and br2.bookingdate < '2010-01-31'
inner join explorer.client c on c.labelno = br1.labelno and c.email <> ''
where br1.bookingdate >= '2009-01-01'
    and br1.bookingdate < '2009-01-31'
    and br2.labelno is null
```

Comment: This worked perfectly although only booking_record.labelno required the index for this to work - now gone from n seconds to 0.14s. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NOT LIKE and NOT IN are most likely the culprits here.

Change `NOT LIKE` to `<>`.  You do not need any 'LIKE' behaviour here, since you're not using any wildcard characters, so you can simply change this to the 'not equal' operator.

Next to that, have you already taken a look at the execution plan and have you investigated whether you have created indexes on the columns that could use an index ?

Comment: He is already using correlated subquery, as he is referencing br1 in that subquery.

Comment: Changed this but it made little difference, will take a look into the indexes

Answer (score 0):

Did you already put indexes on the where fields? Not in and not like is known to be slow, so maybe you can avoid this statements.

Answer (score 0):

'Not in' tends be be slow.
Try something like this, make sure labelno is indexed in both tables.

```
select c.title, c.initial, c.surname, c.labelno, c.email, br1.bookingdate 
from explorer.booking_record br1
inner join explorer.client c
on c.labelno = br1.labelno
and email not like ''
where br1.bookingdate >= '2009-01-01'
and br1.bookingdate < '2009-01-31'
and Not Exists (Select 1 from explorer.booking_record br2 where br2.labelno = br1.labelno and br2.bookingdate >= '2010-01-01' and br2.bookingdate < '2010-01-31')
```